# The Audio playback notification is still visible when the playback stops

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, notifications, react-native-track-player

I'm using react-native-track-player@3.2.0. When I closed the application, The audio stopped but the playback notification was still visible.

Here is my track player setup code in index.js file.

```
const trackSetup = async () => await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer({
waitForBuffer: false}).then( async () => {
await TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
  // stoppingAppPausesPlayback: true,
  android: {
    appKilledPlaybackBehavior:
      AppKilledPlaybackBehavior.StopPlaybackAndRemoveNotification,
  },
  notificationCapabilities: [
    Capability.Play,
    Capability.Pause,
    Capability.JumpBackward,
    Capability.JumpForward,
    Capability.SeekTo,
  ],
  capabilities: [
    Capability.Play,
    Capability.Pause,
    Capability.JumpBackward,
    Capability.JumpForward,
    Capability.SeekTo,
  ],
  compactCapabilities: [Capability.Play, Capability.Pause],
});
console.log(AppState.currentState, 'Track Player Setup...');});
```

Kindly help/guide me to fix this issue. Every help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
AppKilledPlaybackBehavior.StopPlaybackAndRemoveNotification
```

works fine for me on the latest version (4.0.1).

Maybe update the package?

Also, in your `App.js`'s useEffect:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        TrackPlayer.reset();
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: Updating the RNTP to the latest version has fixed the issue.